# Ubuntu 18.10 sets fonts too small at highest screen resolutions

Tags: fonts, display-resolution, 18.10

I know this question has been asked and answered for previous versions of Ubuntu, but in my searches I have not seen anything directly related to v. 18.10. I am running Ubuntu 18.10 on a System 76 Lemur laptop, with an Intel® Core™ i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4 and an Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) processor.

At screen resolutions of 1920x1080 and 1680x1050, the system-wide fonts are so small as to be almost unreadable.

One suggested solution has been to adjust the scale in Settings/Displays, but in Ubuntu 18.10 this only toggles between 100 and 200%, neither one of which is satisfactory.

Another proposed solution has been to go to Settings/Universal Access and choose the text size; again, in 18.10 I can only choose between normal or Large text, and I have already set it to Large. This helps the system fonts, such as in the Settings dialogs, but does not help header fonts on applications like Firefox or Thunderbird.

I'd appreciate some more up to date advice on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Laptop - Installed Ubuntu 18.10 on an HP x360 i5-8250U 8th Gen CPU with Intel 620 UHD Graphics.

To solve the display issue, you need to use the **Gnome Tweak tool**

First ensure the Universe repositories are enabled - In Software & Updates tool, ensure all the Universe Repos are selected.

Click on the Reload Button to update Software & Updates Library Info

then open a terminal window and type:

**sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool**

Once installed, open the Tweak tool from the Apps Menu navigate to the Fonts Section.

Set the Interface, Document & Legacy text to **12 points**
Set Monospace to **14 points**
Hinting should be set to **Slight**
AntiAliasing should be set to **Subpixel**

Scaling should be between **1.00 and no more that 1.04** for the screen ( more preferential than actual necessity.

Apart from the other very handy OS Tweaks within the app, your text viewing woes should be resolved

:)